# Displaying animations during loading screens

Tags: ios, multithreading, loading

Games like Karateka (which uses [UDK](http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/)) seem to be able to asynchronously load GL assets as well as display animation.

The splash is incredibly short, then presumably their glView shows up.

I can think of 2 ways to simultaneously load textures, models and assets into OpenGL:

1) Create 2 contexts: the "real" one (which is doing the loading) and a "fake" one (which will be on a separate viewcontroller.. on a separate thread.)  I'm not sure if this will work however as I don't know if you can create a 2nd GL context on *not the main thread*.

2) Cut the load sequence into small, small jobs.  Each iteration of your draw loop, load one tiny asset (like a single texture or a single model).
The effect of this is probably a *much* longer total loading time!

Are either of these 2 right or are they both wrong?  Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Are either of these 2 right or are they both wrong? I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching, I came across the concept of [EAGL Sharegroups](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts/WorkingwithOpenGLESContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH2-SW5).

[image]

It seems as though iOS designers really thought things through, because EAGLShareGroup is *exactly* what I need here.

Docs say EAGL Sharegroups are useful "When you want your application to be able to create new OpenGL ES objects on a thread other than the main thread for the renderer. In this case, a second context runs on a separate thread and is devoted to fetching data and creating resources. After the resource is loaded, the first context can bind to the object and use it immediately."

Creating a new context with the same sharegroup is easy:

```
EAGLContext* secondContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:[firstContext API]
                               sharegroup: [firstContext sharegroup]];
```

It's ok to read the same OpenGL object on multiple contexts with the same sharegroup **provided the object is not being modified.**

While a GL object **is** being modified, **you may not read that object on another context**.  So you can't try and render the texture you are loading on one context with the other context until you are 100% sure the first context is done loading first.

After an object has been modified, you have to re-bind it on all contexts to see the changes.

So much for cutting my code up into little bits!!